# React Native - component callback animates a view first time but not on subsequent calls

Tags: react-native, animation, callback

I have an animation which is triggered via a callback function sent to a component in render(). The animation is just some text moving from outside the right edge of the screen across the screen and off the left side. The first time the callback is triggered it works perfectly, but on subsequent callbacks nothing can be seen and there are no errors. Relevant code below:

```
     import { Animated, Easing....} from 'react-native';
        
        class Play extends Component {
          constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {currSectName:"Intro",  
            sectNameXcord: new Animated.Value(Dimensions.get('window').width),....}
          }
    
         sectNameTraverse = (newSect) =>{
            this.state.currSectName = newSect;
            this.state.sectNameXcord = new Animated.Value(Dimensions.get('window').width);
    
            //run the animation
            Animated.timing(
              this.state.sectNameXcord,
              {
                toValue: -320,
                duration: 3000, // the duration of the animation
                easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation 
                useNativeDriver: true
              }
            ).start((res)=>{
                console.log(res);
            }); 
          } 
    
          render() {
               return (
                 <>
                  <Animated.View style={{position: 'absolute',top:100,
transform: [{translateX: this.state.sectNameXcord }]}}>
                    <Text style={{ color:"white",opacity:0.5,fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight: 'bold',fontSize:99}}>
                     {this.state.currSectName}
                    </Text>
                  </Animated.View>
    
                 <Player
                 sectionChange={(newSect) => {this.sectNameTraverse(newSect)}}
                 />
          }
```

On subsequent callbacks the following is true:

- the state variables are updated and correct for the next animation
- the callback of Animated.timing().start() shows {"finished": true} after the duration period as if it has executed correctly BUT nothing shows up on the screen
- no errors are thrown

I'm guessing it may have something to do with instances/binding but I'm not good enough
with React Native to fix it. Been stuck on it for 2 days and could really do with some help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mutate the state. you should be using '`setState`' to update the state.

```
  sectNameTraverse = (newSect) => {
    this.setState(
      { 
        currSectName:newSect,
        sectNameXcord: new Animated.Value(Dimensions.get('window').width)
        },
      () => {
        //run the animation
        Animated.timing(this.state.sectNameXcord, {
          toValue: -320,
          duration: 3000, // the duration of the animation
          easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start((res) => {
          console.log(res);
        });
      }
    );
  };
```

here is the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@nilesh.nvs/6b22aa) i created.

Comment: Thanks for that. It now throws a "Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). 
Render methods should be a pure function of props and state." But I'll mark it as solved because the animation does behave as required.